# WARN [CommonsLogger.java:60] ognl.MethodFailedException: Method failed for object [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:([Ljava.lang.String;)]

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, ognl

I have an object which need to be updated, the following form is used to update it.
I have an attribute called `createDate` that I do not want to be changed when I update the record therefore I did not include it in the form, but when I submit the form it changes the value of `createDate` to null.

```
<s:form method="POST" autocomplete="on" action="update">
    <input type="hidden" name="user.id" value="${user.id}"/>
   ....
</s:form>
```

**Code**

```
final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
try {
    final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.update(user);
        if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {    
            tx.commit();
        }
        return "SUCCESS";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Failed";
    }
} finally {
    HibernateUtil.closeSession();
}
```

**User class**

```
....
@Column(name = "createdate")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}
```

I supposed it changes the value to `null` because the field has not been included in the form so I added the following code to my form, although the HTML source of the page show the correct value of `createDate` but when I submit the form it throws following exception.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user.createDate" value="${user.createDate}"/>
```

**Exception after adding input hidden for createDate**

```
INFO:   2014-02-26 12:37:25,896 -  WARN [CommonsLogger.java:60] ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setCreateDate" failed for object com.myproject.myclasses.User@2d680c36 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.myproject.myclasses.User.setCreateDate([Ljava.lang.String;)]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1305)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1494)
    at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
    at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:27)
        ......
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing seems to be related with argument that `setCreateDate()` is expecting. Since your method is declared as `setCreateDate(Date)` it is not compatible with `setCreateDate(String)`, which is expected to be called when you submit the form.

In order to update the current model object, you will have to retrieve it from DB using the submitted `Id`, update the pertinent fields and then call `session.update()`. You code will look like

```
public void updateUserInfo(User user) {
    Session s = getSession();
    Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
    User u = (User) s.load(User.class, user.getId());
    u.setAddress(user.getAddress());
    u.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    s.update(u);
    t.commit();
    closeSession();
}
```

More informations about Hibernate listeners to update fields just before persisting an entity.
If you want to set the `createDate` field just before your record is persisted, you can use

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    createDate = new Date();
}
```

The methods annotated with `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` are called just before Hibernate persist the entity for the first time or update it, respectively. You can get more information [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html).

EDIT: I've notice you are using the `Session API` of Hibernate. In this case, the suggestion above won't work. In order to get it working with your current implementation, you should use the [Hibernate events API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html).

First, create an interface for objects that have to be updated just before it will be persisted (something like this)

```
public interface Dateable {

    void setCreateDate(Date date);
}
```

Modify your `User` class to implement that interface.

```
public class User implements Dateable {
   //...
}
```

Then create a `Listener` that listens for the `SaveOrUpdateEvent` on `Dateable` entities and modifies the create property:

```
import org.hibernate.event.SaveOrUpdateEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener;

public class SaveOrUpdateDateListener extends DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) {
        if (event.getObject() instanceof Dateable) {
            Dateable record = (Dateable) event.getObject();
            record.setCreateDate(new Date());
        }
        super.onSaveOrUpdate(event);
    }
}
```

Finally, configure the above listener via `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
      .....       
        <event type="save-update">
            <listener class="SaveOrUpdateDateListener"/>
        </event>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I've update the answer whit more detail about the JPA annotations.

Comment: I am using hibernate does this code work with hibernate? is there any other method to do it ? should I retrieve the createDate and put it into new object before being persisted?

Comment: Yes, it does. Hibernate implements JPA specification. You can get an instance of `Date` from somewhere else and assign it to `createDate` or create a new instance (as in the example).

Comment: all right, how about if I retrieve the value of createDate from DB and put it into the new object's createDate and then update the new object session.update(user); in this case correct value will be overridden on the createDate field on DB. As the problem is that, currently everytime I try to update the record it is overridding the value of createDate by Null.

Comment: I apologize for the misleading information. The `@PrePersist` annotation will only work if you use Hibernate via `JPA`. As you are using `Session API`, you should follow the steps above to register a listener that will do what `@PrePersist` does. Concerning your question about `createDate` being overridden, is this `Date` retrieved from DB different than `null`?

Comment: Lets say the value in DB is 2014-1-1 when I retrieve the record and then submit the form, as I do not include the value of createDate hibernate replace its value with Null, (after updating the value of createDate will be Null). I am asking how about if I retrieve its value (2014-1-1) from DB then put it into the object's createDate variable before updating the object?

Comment: I'm afraid that, in your case, you will have to retrieve the entity from DB using the submitted ID, update only the pertinent fields and then call `session.update()`.

Comment: I've just update the answer with a snippet of what it will look like.